# Catching an Exception Thrown From an Anonymous Namespace Initialization

Tags: c++

I get an unhandled exception error when throwing an exception from the constructor of a class that is constructed in an anonymous namespace. How can I catch the exception? Here's a simplified example of the error with an attempt to catch it in Main.cpp:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Exception.hpp"
#include "Namespace.hpp"

int main()
try
{
    return 0;
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    exception.show();
    return 1;
}
```

Exception.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Exception
{
    std::string m_error;

public:
    Exception(std::string error) : m_error(error){};
    void show(){ std::cout<<m_error<<"\n"; }
};
```

Namespace.hpp:

```
#pragma once

namespace Namespace
{

};
```

Namespace.cpp:

```
#include "Namespace.hpp"

#include "Class.hpp"

namespace
{
    Class test_class{};
};
```

Class.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "Exception.hpp"

class Class
{
public:
    Class(){ throw Exception{"Error Message\n"}; }
};
```

Comment: 1. Constructors should not throw exceptions. 2. Your code does not throw an exception

Comment: @EdHeal: "Constructors should not throw exceptions" - of course they should, if initialisation failed. How else would you indicate failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable you declare in the anonymous namespace is like any other global variable, it's constructed *before* `main` is called, so the exception is thrown without anyone even being able to catch it.

Comment: @SelymAI Like Ed Heal commented, don't throw exceptions in a constructor. Instead add e.g. a secondary `init` or `open` function which can throw exceptions. Also, it doesn't what you do in the constructor, if you create a global variable of the class then it's constructor is going to be called before `main` is called.